# Fiber (dark or lit) maps and data

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, internet, fcc

I'm looking for any publicly available data on where optical fiber (for Internet connectivity) is physically laid across the US. While there are commercial services that sell some of this data, and some limited datasets for particular cities / areas / network providers are available, is there anything like a federal database for this? For instance, FCC maintains data for where antennas (for microwave communication, etc.) are located. Anything similar for fiber?

EDIT: I'm more interested in long-haul fiber (i.e. wide area / between cities, etc.) than in fiber-to-the-home data.

Comment: Based on Skram's suggestion, I had put in a request to an FCC Data Officer. The response was that the FCC doesn't collect such data.

Answer (score 3):

BroadbandMap.gov, by the FCC, has a raster map of fiber to the end user at http://www.broadbandmap.gov/technology/fiber-to-the-end-user

Unfortunately it does not seem to have the data available as anything other than a tile service.

*Edit 1:* You might consider requesting the data from a [FCC Data Officer](http://www.fcc.gov/data/officers)

*Edit 2:* Also, have you seen http://www.telecomramblings.com/network-maps/usa-fiber-backbone-map-resources/ which at least tries to link to each carrier/provider's maps which could then be used to create a dataset from?

Comment: Thanks Skram, I'm more interested in long-haul fiber, but your suggestion on putting in a request to a Data Officer is appreciated. I'll put in a request, and if something comes by, I'll be sure to post an update here.

Comment: @user2565476 ah, I understand now. Take a look at http://www.telecomramblings.com/network-maps/usa-fiber-backbone-map-resources/ which I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Skram, the telecoramblings link does go some way; it's unfortunate that there're only images etc. instead of data.